# XPATH: Specific word in paragraph

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have been trying to figure out how to get the exact xpath for e.g. the third word in a paragraph:

e.g.:

```
<p>Here is some text</p>
```

then if I want the third word ("some"), I can't figure out how to single that out using xpath. However, the focal point here is not to get the exact match of the word "some", instead it is to get the third word (whatever it may be).

I have been trying with this: ../p[3], but doesn't help. I use python and the scrapy framework.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Retrieve the text node as a whole with an XPath expression and tokenize the string in Python. XPath 1.0 is very bad at string manipulation.

Comment: Scrapy uses XPath 1.0, and as Mathias mentions, you're not going to want to do this with `substring()`/`substring-before()`/`substring-after()` types of string operations.  Pop out to Python after retrieving the text.

Comment: Okay thx guys! I will do it in python instead then. Was just hoping it would work with xpath. :)

Comment: Sorry I cant upvote your comments. They really were helpful. thx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using scrapy, as this question was tagged, consider using scrapy's `.re()` support, i.e:

```
>>> response.xpath('//p/text()').re('\w+')[2]
u'some'
```